# How to make bootable win7 usb for install purposes

Tags: windows-7, usb, boot

Hi all I have win7 x86 and I want to create bootable win7 x64 usb.

I am following this tutorial: [LINK](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7vista-from-usb-drive-detailed-100-working-guide/)
Problem is that I get error that my current version of system is x86 and it's not compatibile with x64.

What can I do to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a bootable Windows 7 x64 USB from an x86 instance using that method. You can do it if you have an ISO of the Windows 7 media (for example if you are a volume licensing customer or TechNet/MSDN subscriber).

If you don't have an ISO, I believe you could create an ISO from your Windows 7 DVD and use this instead.

I haven't done this personally, but [here is a guide](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2432-usb-windows-7-installation-key-drive-create.html?ltr=U) (follow Option One). Sorry that it's a link to an external site; it wouldn't make sense for me to write it up (or summarize) as I haven't validated the process.

Comment: I get an error that files are copied but it didn't make it bootable. Something is wrong with my bootsec

Comment: yes it worked nicely

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ISO, use this tutorial. It is much easier and is basically point and click. I use it from time to time and never had any issues.

http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-create-bootable-windows-7-usb-to-install-windows-7-from-usb-flash-drive-using-windows-7-dvdusb-tool/

http://download.cnet.com/Windows-7-USB-DVD-Download-Tool/3000-18513_4-10972600.html

Answer (score 0):

[Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) is the best tool there is for that job.

> When you choose to download most software from the Microsoft Store, you have the option of using Download Manager or downloading from your browser. However, when you purchase Microsoft Windows 7 from Microsoft Store, you have an additional choice to make: whether to download a collection of compressed files or to download an ISO file. An ISO file combines all the Windows 7 installation files into a single uncompressed file.
>
> If you choose to download an ISO file (so that you can create a bootable file from a DVD or USB flash drive), copy your Windows 7 ISO file onto your media and, run the Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool. After you do this, you can install Windows 7 onto your computer directly from the USB flash drive or DVD.
>
> **NOTE:** When you download the ISO file, you must copy the file onto a USB flash drive or a DVD to install Windows 7. When you're ready to install Windows 7, insert the USB flash drive into your USB port or insert your DVD into your DVD drive, and then run Setup.exe from the root folder on the drive.
>
> The advantage to following this process and creating bootable media is that it allows you to install Windows 7 without having to first run an existing operating system on your machine. If you change the boot order of drives in your computer's BIOS, you can run the Windows 7 installation directly from your USB flash drive or from a DVD when you first turn your computer on. (Please see the documentation for your computer for information about how to change the BIOS boot order of drives.)